# Xamarin Forms : How do i navigate to another page from another c# class

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation

I have a main page A with a click button. Once the button is clicked, it will call a method on another c# class and trigger a new page B from this new c# class. However, the page A does not refresh with page B.
If I call this new page B from code inside page A, then it will refresh with page B. 
May I know why and how do i solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

from within a `Page`

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new PageB());
```

from a non-page class

```
App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new PageB());
```

both approaches assume your current page is enclosed in a `NavigationPage`